# Error building cv_bridge on RaspberryPi

Tags: ros, opencv, raspberrypi, cv-bridge, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build some libfreenect drivers (for the kinect) and I do a rosmake and it fails in cv_bridge complaining about some image formats (e.g., CV_YUV2RGB_UYVY, see below for more).

- RaspberryPi (ARM)
- [Raspbian Linux](http://www.raspbian.org) - Debian for RaspberryPi
- OpenCV 2.3 installed
- ROS fuerte

What am I doing wrong??

[kevin@raspberrypi freenect_stack]$ CC="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++" rosmake freenect_stack
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['freenect_stack']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121103-133147
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['freenect_stack'] to:
['freenect_camera', 'freenect_launch', 'libfreenect']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure [PASS] [ 45.26 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib [PASS] [ 17.47 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport [PASS] [ 17.48 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< polled_camera [PASS] [ 15.69 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps [PASS] [ 2.14 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers [PASS] [ 14.33 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 [PASS] [ 0.09 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_bridge: 49.9 sec ]                                                                                          [ 1 Active 17/50 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

```
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

### -- Build files have been written to: /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build
cd build && make -l1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' make[2]: Entering directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/src/cv_bridge.o distcc[7294] ERROR: compile /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp on arch failed distcc[7294] (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: remote compilation of '/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp' failed, retrying locally distcc[7294] Warning: failed to distribute /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp to arch, running locally instead /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function ‘std::map<std::pair<cv_bridge::Format, cv_bridge::Format>, std::vector<int> > cv_bridge::getConversionCodes()’: /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:179:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2GRAY_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:180:46: error: ‘CV_YUV2RGB_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:181:46: error: ‘CV_YUV2BGR_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:182:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2RGBA_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:183:47: error: ‘CV_YUV2BGRA_UYVY’ was not declared in this scope distcc[7294] ERROR: compile /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp on localhost failed make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/src/cv_bridge.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/kevin/ros/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package cv_bridge written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121103-133147/cv_bridge/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge [FAIL] [ 49.97 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package cv_bridge.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 18 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/kevin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121103-133147

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47393/error-building-cv_bridge-on-raspberrypi/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It just happened to me as well and I thought I would share the solution.

Your OpenCV version is too old. You probably downloaded opencv using the prebuilt binaries which will not work. You will need to compile from source.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prarobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3114/prarobo/) on 2013-05-28**:
I am also having error with installing cv_bridge on raspbian. About installing opencv from source, are you referring to vision_opencv that comes with ros or the opencv from debian repositories?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-29**:
back then there was no openCV debian ;)
You should use the debian package now and everything should work without problems